# Rails + Heroku + Devise: Sign in page does not work but log doesn't say anything

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, devise

I have an app

http://buzzme.herokuapp.com/

but when I click sign in: http://buzzme.herokuapp.com/clients/sign_in

It gives me an error `We're sorry, but something went wrong.`

But heroku logs don't say anything:

```
  =0ms service=15ms status=500 bytes=1754
  2015-05-03T02:38:27.676212+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/clients/sign_in" host=buzzme.herokuapp.com request_id=38444765-b318-4719-8017-ff9fc9dd5031 fwd="207.41.179.38" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=17ms status=500 bytes=1754
  2015-05-03T02:38:27.715718+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/clients/sign_in" host=buzzme.herokuapp.com request_id=49cba466-6bf5-4413-b25e-aeec7a0bac57 fwd="207.41.179.38" dyno=web.1 connect=4ms service=17ms status=500 bytes=1754
  2015-05-03T02:39:06.600569+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=POST path="/clients/sign_in" host=buzzme.herokuapp.com request_id=fd6acefb-22ff-4e49-a50b-5a70f21f25de fwd="207.41.179.38" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=9ms status=422 bytes=328
```

How would I debug this? I already changed the log level to debug but it doesn't say anything.

Comment: did you try heroku run rake db:migrate?

Comment: If the above comment does not work could you provide your routes.rb and also were you able to run the following locally?